# Ubuntu Terminal without password?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, password

I open a lot of terminals each day. And everytime I press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and it opens a terminal and asks me to put in my password:

[image: Terminal open example]

Is there a way to open the terminal without asking for a password?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS - with Gnome

Comment: Do you always run every command in Terminal as root?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is **not** normal behaviour, and if you don't remember setting this up, don't put in your password and consider it a security issue until you can be sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are being asked for your password every time you open the application, then it's likely that your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc` file have been modified to include a command that requires `sudo` to run. Open these files, look for the command that requires `sudo`, and edit accordingly.

In the event that you have a script calling a command that *must* be run with `sudo` every time you start Terminal, consider adding a `sudoers` exception. You can do so like this:

1. Open Terminal (if it's not already open) and enter your password
2. Open `visudo`:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
3. Add the exception near the bottom of the file:

   ```
   user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/{command}
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `/path/to` with the proper path and `{command}` to the proper command.</sup>
4. Exit, saving the file.

Comment: I am very curious which command is in there and how it got there. If my system started asking for root for no reason I would personally consider it a security issue. Hopefully there is a good reason for it after all.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, especially matigo.
I attached a script location at the end of ~/.bashrc, this bash script is basically checking if all the devices are mounted properly. If that isn't the case it is attempting to mount them. Because this is requiring sudo privileges, it was the reason the password prompt kept appearing.
Now the Terminal opens up normally and as desired. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to open the terminal without asking for a password?

Yes, in fact, *you already do so*. The terminal is just a text interface to the underlying program, and it is that underlying program that is asking you for a password.

Apparently, that program is `sudo`, which is usually used to run a command with elevated privileges. Either your shell is running `sudo`, or your terminal is running a custom command that runs `sudo`, or (unlikely) your terminal is running `sudo` directly.

In any case, this automatic running of `sudo` is both an inconvenience and a potential security issue, so you should check your terminal and shell configurations. Since you use the terminal a lot, you should already know how to do this, but [matigo’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1400291/1142770) has more information.